# Print output lines progressively of a shell command in a php web page

Tags: php, shell

I'm trying to display in a text area the output lines of a command **progressively**.
Here is the code I already have. It's **partially** working:

```
if (!empty($_POST["ACTION"])) {
    $fds = array(
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),
        2 => array("pipe", "w"),
    );
    $cmd = "command -option --debug 2>&1";
    $res = proc_open($cmd, $fds, $pipes);
    if (!is_resource($res))
        $res = false;
}
echo '<form method="post" action="?itemtype=item">';

if (is_resource($res)) {
    ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0);

echo '<textarea readonly="readonly" id="action_done" style="display: block; width: 99%; height: 280px">';
do {
    $read = $pipes;
    $exc = $pipes;
    $write = array();
    $nb = stream_select($read, $write, $exc, static::TIMEOUT, 0);
    // Error
    if ($nb === FALSE) {
         echo "UNKNOWN ERROR\n";
         break;
    }

    // Timeout
    if ($nb === 0) {
        echo "ERROR: command timed out!\n";
        break;
    }

    if (count($exc)) {
        echo "UNKNOWN ERROR\n";
        break;
    }
    foreach ($read as $stream){
         echo htmlspecialchars(fread($stream, 8192), ENT_HTML5 | ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
         flush();
         ob_flush();
    }
    if (feof($pipes[1])){
         break;
    }
} while(1);
$info = proc_get_status($res);
if ($info === false) {
     echo "ERROR: could not determine process status\n";
} else {
   if ($info["signaled"])
       echo "Command terminated by signal ${info['termsig']}\n";
   if ($info["stopped"])
       echo "Command stopped by signal ${info['stopsig']}\n";
       echo "Command exited with return code ${info['exitcode']}\n";
}

proc_close($res);
echo '</textarea>';
}
```

The reason why I say it's partially working is because it stops at some point in the while loop. And I can't figure out why.
More precisely, i don't have the end of the output (it's supposed to tell me that everything worked fine) but it doesn't.
It only works well when the command detect an error, the loop beaks fine.
So if someone knows what is wrong in this code and tell me what to change
OR
Know how to do it differently (i.e display the output of the command **progressively** in the text area) and tell me how...
It would be huge.
Thanks !!

Comment: Turn on error reporting an check if any error exist or not

Comment: Error reporting is turned on with E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT.
I don't have any error :(

Comment: Ok, I finally have an error : It says that pipes is not defined, and ob_flush has no buffer to flush...But i don't understand, "pipes" is defined...

Comment: what error are you getting?